# Ubuntu 17.04 - Installing TLP asks for additional dependencies like postfix

Tags: 17.04, postfix, tlp

Have issue with installing TLP in Ubuntu 17.04. It brings up new dependencies like postfix, which I don't want to install in a home laptop. Earlier versions of ubuntu did not ask for postfix.

Comment: Install it with `--no-install-recommends` if you are using `apt`, it is smartmontools that is installing postfix.

Comment: @gdahlm Please post your comment as an answer, so the OP can accept it if he ever visits this site again.

Answer (score 0):

Install it with --no-install-recommends if you are using apt, it is smartmontools that is installing postfix.

*Posting comment as answer per reqeuest*